# DLL load failed:specified module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

On versions of Python 2.7 -3.4 after successfull installation of lxml, ***from* *lxml* *import* *etree*** returns message: DLL load failed:specified module not found. How to fix it?

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you install it? What the error output?

Comment: Windows 10(x64). Installed from offical site python.org. Output: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.